# iOS: Is this the proper way to setup a database location under the application support folder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database

I have a sql file that needs to be stored in my App. A user on this site recommend me to store it underneath the Application Support folder. This is the path directory that I am using with my fmDatabase library.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = [paths firstObject];
self.dataBasePath = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"Email.sqlite"];
self.fmDataBase = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:self.dataBasePath];
```

Everything seems to be working fine. However, I am a little nervous that I may be doing something wrong. I am using the Application Support directory because I don't want the OS or an update to interfere with the Database. I would use the document directory ,but my App supports file share so the user can mess it up.

Comment: As I stated in my answer to your previous question, you should use a folder after `Application Support` and put your file in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: Best place to store sql database in this scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983519/ios-best-place-to-store-sql-database-in-this-scenario)

Answer (score 0):

*`(application_home)/Library`* path is a place where you can create custom subdirectories for files you want backed up but not exposed to the user.
create a directory such as *`(application_home)/Library/Database`* and save files there.
for mac os x with sqlite The convention is to store it in the Application Support folder .
 i.e. in *`~/Library/Application Support/YourAppNam*/database.db`*

Answer (score 0):

I think the data will be saved on the Application Support Folder in Mac platform, for iOS, the default is xxx/Library.
I don't see any dangerous element on this, because you can save to different folder as long as you can load it from right path.